# Get current application instance using websphere api?

Tags: java, caching, websphere

I've an app which is deployed on to a cluster with 2 jvms. The web application has cache implemented using Mbeans and the cache runs on each jvm. the cache is refreshed with a request pattern */refresh. The problem is that when the request goes through ODR, it routes it to only one server and the cache for only one server is refreshed. How do I solve this problem? Cache replication? I think it might be lot of work to implement cache replication. Any other solutions? Websphere api's ?

if I get the current instance of the application, I'm thinking of using AdminClient to get the clusters and then call the request on all the nodes on which the application is installed except for the current instance.

Comment: What are you using to implement your cache?

Answer (score 2):

The Websphere way to do this is to use the DynaCache feature with DRS. The DynaCache is a kind of a hashmap, which can be distributed across the DRS cluster members. The dynacache has an API, DistributedMap, which extends the java.util.Map. 
There are also a lot of configuration (Through AdminConsole and cachespec.xml) and monitoring possibilities (PMI with TPV).

Technical overview:
http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/lnxinfo/v3r0m0/index.jsp?topic=%2Fliaag%2Fcache%2Fpubwasdynacachoverview.htm

DistributedMap API
http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/adiehelp/v5r1m1/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.wasee.doc%2Finfo%2Fee%2Fjavadoc%2Fee%2Fcom%2Fibm%2Fwebsphere%2Fcache%2FDistributedMap.html

A good article from developerworks
http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/websphere/library/techarticles/0906_salvarinov/0906_salvarinov.html

Answer (score 1):

The crude way we did something similar was to directly hit each Web Container on its own port. If you're able to reach them, that is.